# Oracle pivot and sequencing with multiple columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm writing a report that (for the sake of simplicity user-side) I'd like to aggregate some data together using an oracle query that will eventually be imported into excel, but may be run automatically to a printer as well, so the processing needs to be done in the query itself.

I'm using oracle, version 10.2.0.5.0 (select version from v$instance).

OK, So i'm using this query;

```
SELECT substr(arg_string,1,4) node,
               substr(numtodsinterval(end_time-start_time,'DAY'), 12, 8) dur,
               row_number() over (order by substr(arg_string,1,4),
                                           start_time) rn
          FROM pro.program_status
          where  prog_name like ('%v8x-6%')
      and    start_time > sysdate - 10;
```

Which returns a dataset resembling the following;

```
NODE DUR      RN
---- -------- ----------
s002 00:25:40 1
s002 00:27:21 2
s002 00:03:20 3
s002 00:27:44 4
...
s004 00:21:29 22
s004 00:22:19 23
s004 00:05:13 24
s004 00:22:47 25
...
s005 00:03:13 42
s005 00:00:46 43
s005 00:02:01 44
s005 00:00:45 45
...
s152 00:01:13 1840
```

And my desired output is as follows;

```
NODE DUR1     DUR2     DUR3
---- -------- -------- ----------
s002 00:25:40 00:27:21 00:03:20
s004 00:21:29 00:22:19 00:05:13
s005 00:03:13 00:00:46 00:02:01
and so on
```

I have tried the following query;

```
SELECT node,
       max( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN dur ELSE NULL END ) dur1,
       max( CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN dur ELSE NULL END ) dur2,
       max( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN dur ELSE NULL END ) dur3
  FROM (SELECT substr(arg_string,1,4) node,
               substr(numtodsinterval(end_time-start_time,'DAY'), 12, 8) dur,
               row_number() over (order by substr(arg_string,1,4),
                                           start_time) rn
          FROM pro.program_status
          where  prog_name like ('%v8x-6%')
          and    start_time > sysdate - 10)
group by node
/
```

However this returns the following result as only 's002' is labeled 1,2 and 3

```
NODE DUR1     DUR2     DUR3     
---- -------- -------- -------- 
s002 00:25:40 00:27:21 00:03:20 
s004
s005
s009
and so on
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious, however after searching through this site and numerous others I cannot seem to get this working properly.

A bit more detail, i do not know how many times each node will appear or how many nodes there will be each day.

Thanks in advance.
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT node,
       max( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN dur ELSE NULL END ) dur1,
       max( CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN dur ELSE NULL END ) dur2,
       max( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN dur ELSE NULL END ) dur3
FROM (SELECT substr(arg_string,1,4) node,
             substr(numtodsinterval(end_time-start_time,'DAY'), 12, 8) dur,
             row_number() over (partition by substr(arg_string,1,4)
                                order by substr(arg_string,1,4), start_time) rn
      FROM pro.program_status
      where  prog_name like ('%v8x-6%')
        and  start_time > sysdate - 10)
group by node
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I don't have enough of a reputation on here to vote up yet (only joined today), but that did the trick perfectly!